# Unity Firebase .ChildAdded listener triggers for all already existing children?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

i need a void to trigger when a new Child is added to a specific branch from my Firebase database.

```
DBreference.Child("Users").Child(User.UserId).Child(chatto).ChildAdded += HandleChildAdded;
```

In the HandleChildAdded void i have a Debug.Log that triggers for every already existing child instead of only when a child is added. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach a listener for the `ChildAdded` event, it is called immediately for each existing child, and then for each child added afterwards. There is no way to change this behavior.

---

If you don't want to receive a notification for existing child nodes, you'll need to exclude those using a query/condition. For example, if all your nodes have a timestamp of when they were added, you can start listening for nodes created after "now" with something like:

```
ref.OrderByChild("timestamp").StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond).ChildAdded...
```

---

If you don't have a timestamp, but for example your node are ordered because you use `Push()`, you could:

1. Read the most recent node with `OrderByKey().LimitToLast(1)`, to determine its key.
2. Then start listening from there with `OrderByKey().StartAt("key from step 1")`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I create nodes by just `SetValueAsync()` to children of said node so that won't work but i figured a way where i see the `ChildrenCount()` at start and only if a variable that increments at `ChildAdded` is greater than the start `ChildrenCount()` it triggers. But idk if it triggers even if the app is closed... Beacuse a Unity notification is sopposed to fire but it doesn't...